# MPAndroidCharts data - argument mismatch; ArrayList<ILineDataSet> cannot be converted to List<String>

Tags: java, mpandroidchart

I'm out of ideas - I have an error and don't know how to avoid it

C:\Users\antos\AndroidStudioProjects\J_Wykres\app\src\main\java\com\example\j_wykres\MainActivity.java:60: error: no suitable constructor found for LineData(ArrayList)
lineData = new LineData(dataSets);
^
constructor LineData.LineData(List) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; ArrayList cannot be converted to List)
constructor LineData.LineData(String[]) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; ArrayList cannot be converted to String[])

```
package com.example.j_wykres;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.Entry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.interfaces.datasets.ILineDataSet;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    LineChart lineChart;
    EditText xEditText, yEditText;
    Button btnInsert, btnShow;

    MyHelper myHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
    LineDataSet lineDataSet = new LineDataSet(getDataValues(),null);
    ArrayList<ILineDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
    LineData lineData = new LineData();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lineChart = findViewById(R.id.mpChart);
        xEditText = findViewById(R.id.editTextX);
        yEditText = findViewById(R.id.editTextY);
        btnInsert = findViewById(R.id.btnInsert);
        btnShow = findViewById(R.id.btnShow);
        myHelper = new MyHelper(this);
        sqLiteDatabase = myHelper.getWritableDatabase();



        exqInsertBtn();
        exqShowBtn();

    }

    private void exqShowBtn() {
        btnShow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                lineDataSet.setLabel("Dupa");
                dataSets.clear();
                dataSets.add(lineDataSet);
                lineData.addDataSet(lineDataSet);
                lineData = new LineData(dataSets);
                lineChart.clear();
                lineChart.setData(lineData);
                lineChart.invalidate();
            }
        });
    }

    private void exqInsertBtn() {
        btnInsert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                float xVal = Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(xEditText.getText()));
                float yVal = Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(yEditText.getText()));
                myHelper.insertData(xVal,yVal);
            }
        });
    }

    private ArrayList<Entry> getDataValues(){
        ArrayList<Entry> dataVals = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] columns = {"xValues","yValues"};
        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query("myTable", columns,null,null,null,null,null);

        for(int i = 0; i<cursor.getCount();i++){
            cursor.moveToNext();
            dataVals.add(new Entry(cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getInt(1))); //tu masz inaczej
        }
        return dataVals;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
ArrayList<ILineDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
```

Should be changed to

```
List<ILineDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
```

The LineData constructor requires a List, not ArrayList.